# Sorting Guava table on values

Tags: java, guava, comparator

Is there any possible way to do that? The expecting effect would be that rowMap and columnMap   entry values would be sorted by value.

The problem is that I cannot create a comparator without the underlying maps in Table.

```
Table table = TreeBasedTable.create(?,?);

Map<String, Map<String, String>> rowMap = table.rowMap();
Map<String, String> thisMapShouldBeSortedByValues = rowMap.get(smth);

Map<String, Map<String, String>> columnMap = table.columnMap();
Map<String, String> thisMapShouldBeSortedByValues = columnMap.get(smth);
```

Now I always have to sort rowMap and columnMap afterwards and allocate new TreeMaps on that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am assuming that by `thisMapShouldBeSortedByValues`, you mean `thisMapShouldBeSortedByKeys`

TreeBasedTable extends RowSortedTable, so the table is only sorted by it's rows, not its columns. Calling `table.columnMap()` gives you an unordered `Map<C, Map<R, V>`.

Since it is sorted by rows, the `table.rowMap` returns a `SortedMap<R, Map<C, V>>`. So the map is sorted on it's row keys, but the `Map<C, V>` value is an unsorted map, hence why calls to `rowMap.get()` returns an unordered map.

The SortedMap you are trying to get from calling table.rowMap(), and then rowMap.get(), can be obtained by instead calling table.rowKeySet() and table.row(R rowKey) like so (You build the map you originally wanted to get by calling `table.rowMap()`:

```
ImmutableSortedMap.Builder<String, SortedMap<String, String>> builder = ImmutableSortedMap.builder();

for (String rowKey : table.rowKeySet()){
     builder.put(rowKey, table.row(rowKey)) ;
}

 SortedMap<String, <SortedMap<String, String>> thisMapIsSortedByKeys = builder.build();
```

Comment: I don't think it's right to say that the TreeBasedTable is not sorted by columns. It's sorted by rows, and the cells in each row are further sorted by columns. As https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table says, "TreeBasedTable, which is essentially backed by a TreeMap<R, TreeMap<C, V>>"