# how to insert values in sorted order in Guava Table values

Tags: java, collections, gson, guava

I've been trying to insert some values in sorted order in Table structure for Guava, below is my piece of code

```
NodeDetails node1 = new NodeDetails();
NodeDetails node2 = new NodeDetails();
NodeDetails node3 = new NodeDetails();

node1.setCLOUDTYPE("aws");
node1.setNODENAME("node1");

node2.setCLOUDTYPE("cloudstack");
node2.setNODENAME("node2");

node3.setCLOUDTYPE("azure");
node3.setNODENAME("node3");

Table<String, String, Object> table = TreeBasedTable.create();
    table.put("vmstat_usage", "cpu_idle", node1);
    table.put("vmstat_usage", "cpu_idle", node2);
    table.put("vmstat_usage", "cpu_idle", node3);
    table.put("vmstat_usage_percent", "cpu_system", node3);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting()
                    .create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(table.rowMap()));
```

Here NodeDetails is implementing Comparable with which I want to sort the values... But when I'm taking the values of rowMap the same is overriding with existing values. So only one object is returning.

If I create TreeMultimap I'm getting all the objects inserted in collection correctly.

I'm trying to create this kind of response through this.

```
{
  "vmstat_usage": {
    "cpu_idle":      {
        "CLOUD_TYPE": "azure",
        "NODE_NAME": "node3",
      },
      {
        "CLOUD_TYPE": "aws",
        "NODE_NAME": "node1",
      },
      {
        "CLOUD_TYPE": "cloudstack",
        "NODE_NAME": "node2",
        "NODE_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS": null
      }
  },
  "vmstat_usage_percent": {
    "cpu_idle": {
      "CLOUD_TYPE": "azure",
      "NODE_NAME": "node3",
    }
  }
}
```

I've gone through this link [Sorting Guava table on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256840/sorting-guava-table-on-values) and found that "table.rowMap returns a SortedMap>. So the map is sorted on it's row keys, but the Map value is an unsorted map"
As suggested here [Java Sort a Guava TreeBasedTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001582/java-sort-a-guava-treebasedtable) I can create a new TreeTable with defined comparator and put my previous Table in there or http://www.wenda.io/questions/2486554/sorting-guava-tables-in-descending-order-based-on-values.html I can create new Ordering while create the Table.

I tried something like this but it's not working.

```
Table<String, String, NodeDetails> table2 = TreeBasedTable.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.natural());
table2.putAll(table);
```

Please give me an example for how to do this.